# How do I change the Site Page grey header on SharePoint Online O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, branding

Does anyone know how to change the default header image on the 'Site Page' on SharePoint online? This a vanilla OOTB Team Site. I think this is the new 2016 content page, comes up as a Site Page content type.

[image: How do I change this grey banner image?]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily customize the page header image of the new Modern Pages in SPO. In order to do that, please follow the given below steps:

- Edit the page

[image]

- Click on Image icon

[image]

- Select the new image or upload it. In my case I have uploaded a new
  image.

[image]

- Save the page

[image]

And you can have your new page header image applied.

Answer (score 0):

Little late but currently you can just delete it if your in edit mode.  To Change the image select the first icon and upload or choose an existing image.

[image]