# How do I change all the default Site Page grey header on SharePoint Online O365

Tags: sharepoint-online

This is connected to [How do I change the Site Page grey header on SharePoint Online O365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205876/how-do-i-change-the-site-page-grey-header-on-sharepoint-online-o365)

But I want to know if it possible to change ALL site pages in a librarys header automatically- either with settings or programmatically. Reason is that I have hundreds of pages, and the grey dark header makes the title hard to read, but changing everything manually will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Create [Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) so you could override default CSS.

Similar thread about checking page library.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d6d56c87-5110-41d0-bcf4-760955f70a7b/i-want-to-apply-application-customiser-to-all-the-modern-pages-under-site-pages-library-in?forum=sharepointdevelopment

The CSS to override default CSS.

```
const css: string = 'div[data-automation-id="titleRegionBackgroundImage"]{background-image:none !important;background-color: coral!important;}';
      if (css) {
          // inject the style sheet
          const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
          let customStyle: HTMLStyleElement = document.createElement("style");
          head.appendChild(customStyle);
          customStyle.title = "MSCustom";
          customStyle.type = "text/css";
          customStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css))
      }
```

Sample result.

[image]